# Methods inherited from Object class

Tags: apex, object

The Apex includes a system class named `Object` which serves as the foundation (superclass) for all standard and custom types.

**Questions**

1. Which methods does the `Object` class contain, and which ones can be overridden?
2. Is there any available documentation regarding the `Object` class? I found that: no (Source: [Object class in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/42594/object-class-in-apex)), but it was 2014.
3. Is there something more than in [Java Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)?

**My small investigation**

`toString()`

```java
public class A {}

System.debug(new A().toString()); // A:[]

public class A {
   public override String toString() {
       return 'Hello toString()';
   }
}

System.debug(new A().toString()); // 'Hello toString()'
```

`equals()`

```java
public class A {}

System.debug(new A().equal('Some String'); // false
```

`hashCode()`

```java
public class A {}

System.debug(new A().hashCode()); // 2069582068
System.debug('Some String'.hashCode()); // 2147069117
```

`clone()`

```java
public class A {}

System.debug(new A().clone());
```

Comment: According to the placeholder created by Illuminated Cloud (I do not know how it is created), Object only has `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString`, and all three are virtual. It's possible that this placeholder has been fabricated by Scott (the dev for IC) or it may be queryable through the tooling API somehow - though on the latter I could not find it in the `ApexClass` table.

Comment: BTW, I feel that the lack of documentation is somewhat ridiculous.

Comment: NB: the previous Q&A you cite has a comment from April by Daniel Ballinger stating: "Object does not currently support a clone method. It only has toString(), equals(), and hashCode(). However, any Apex Class that you define will have an implicit clone method that you can override if you want to". Daniel is one of the PMs for Apex at Salesforce, so should know what he's talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Which methods does the Object class contain, and which ones can be overridden?**

`equals`, `hashCode` and `toString`.

**Is there any available documentation regarding the Object class?**

It has never been properly documented. I've asked if there is a reason why it cannot be.

**Is there something more than in Java Object?**

No.

**Also...**

Note that, as per a comment by Daniel Ballinger (PM for Apex at Salesforce):

> any Apex Class that you define will have an implicit clone method that you can override if you want to.

I.e. `clone` is not on `Object` but the class implicitly receives this as part of its definition. This is a bit weird, but Apex isn't formally specified as such, at least not for people outside Salesforce.

The `toString` method is another weird one; while `String` supports it, for example, that isn't the case with `Id`. The important point here is that not all API classes actually extend `Object`, but all custom apex classes do.

Comment: Thank you Phil!